# POST second variable from HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have an html form that sends two variables, like so:

tablegen.php

```
 <?php
include 'email.php';
function connect(){

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","asda") or die ('Error Reaching Database');
    mysql_select_db("MathGuide");


}   
    //Area  51, idk what I'm doing

function tableGen($x) {
$term=$x;
$sql = mysql_query("select * from student_info where ID like '$term'");
$output = "";
$output .= "<h1>STUDENT DATA for ID: $term</h1>";
$output .=  "<table>";
$output .=  "<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Starter Project</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>KDs Completed in your Course</th>
<th>Projects Completed</th>
<th>Project 1</th>
<th>P1KD1</th>
<th>P1KD2</th>
<th>P1KD3</th>
<th>P1KD4</th>
<th>P1KD5</th>
<th>Project 2</th>
<th>P2KD1</th>
<th>P2KD2</th>
<th>P2KD3</th>
<th>P2KD4</th>
<th>P2KD5</th>
<th>Project 3</th>
<th>P3KD1</th>
<th>P3KD2</th>
<th>P3KD3</th>
<th>P3KD4</th>
<th>P3KD5</th>
<th>Project 4</th>
<th>P4KD1</th>
<th>P4KD2</th>
<th>P4KD3</th>
<th>P4KD4</th>
<th>P4KD5</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$output .=  "<tr><td>";
$output .=  $row['ID'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Starter Project'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Course'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['KDs completed in your course'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Projects Completed'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td></tr>";

}
$output .=  "</table>";
echo $output;
echo "<form action='email.php?check&;' method = 'post'>";
echo "<p><b>Do you want this in an email?</b></p>";
echo "<input type='text' name='send'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='output' value='$output'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send!' />";
echo "</form>";


}
error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born

?>
```

email.php

```
   <html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color:#1C2932;
}
p {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 18px;
color: #989898;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['check'])) {
$email = $_GET['check'];
$message = $_POST['output'];
$headers = array(
'From: summitmathguide@gmail.com',
'Content-Type: text/html',
'Content-Type: text/css',
);
mail($email,'HTML Email',$message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
echo "<p>Email Sent!</p>";
error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The variable `email` posts `send` because that was the name of the text box. How do I set a variable equal to `$output`?

Above is the code for tablegen.php, and email.php.

Thanks much for any help?

Comment: check is the username, which is sent through the form. the line if(isset).... checks to see if an email was entered, before executing the rest of the code. I just want to set a variable equal to "$output".

Comment: see my answer replace `form` and email.php edit and test again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with  hidden input

```
 $escaped_output = htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES);
 echo "<form action='email.php' method = 'post'>";
 echo "<p><b>Do you want this in an email?</b></p>";
 echo "<input type='text' name='check'/>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='output' value='$escaped_output'/>";// hidden input
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send!' />";
 echo "</form>";
```

and put `if(isset($_POST['check'])) {` instead of `if(isset($_GET['check'])) {`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
   $email = $_POST['check'];
   $message = $_POST['output'];
   $headers = array(
               'From: summitmathguide@gmail.com',
               'Content-Type: text/html',
               'Content-Type: text/css',
           );
   mail($email,'HTML Email',$message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
   echo "<p>Email Sent!</p>";
   error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use hidden field

```
 echo "<form action='email.php?check&;' method = 'get'>";
 echo "<p><b>Do you want this in an email?</b></p>";
 echo "<input type='text' name='send'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='output' value='$output'>";// hidden input
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send!' />";
 echo "</form>";
```

Comment: with send form with get  method in php `$_POST['send']` is empty

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this answer! It seems like it did the job. However, no email is sent, and I don't get the "Email Sent" echo. The SMTP server is configured correctly, and is able to send emails. Do you have any idea on what the problem might be? I have updated the above code to reflect the changes.

Comment: @user2200321 use my answer form i think problem is for check is empty and form method  is get in Praveen kalal answer

Comment: @user2200321 are you replace `check` with email? or use  `check=email`

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur Hm..same issue with yours as well.

Comment: Ah this prints out the value of $output, which is a table. I guess this is a start! However, it still doesn't send the email.

Comment: It also prints this before: Array ( [send] => email@email.com [output] =>

Comment: @user2200321 problem is for form method it must be post

Comment: @user2200321 and put `$email = $_GET['check'];` instead `$email = $_POST['check'];`

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur changed it to "post" and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur changed the $email line too, and the exact same thing is happening.

Comment: @user2200321 see `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_GET);` value is set correctly?

Comment: print_r($_POST) gives me the whole table, as well as the email. print_r($GET) gives me this: Array ( [check] => )

Comment: @user2200321 are you see `check=email` in `print_r($_GET);` result

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur I'm not exactly sure what you mean?

Comment: i think `check` is not set `check` struct must be  `check=email`  as in my answer if you replace `check` with email, `check` is empty

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @user2200321 easy instead of replace  `check` use `check=myemail@example.com` or if you can send my code to edit it for you

Comment: where do I put this? Also, check is the email address being entered, how would I set it equal to something?

Comment: Through the text box. "check" is the variable equal the person's email, which they enter into a text box.

Comment: @user2200321 see my edit answer set `check` as hidden input it better

Comment: Hm, now email.php does not load at all.

Comment: @user2200321 what? if you send me code i can solve problem very fast

Comment: Ok sure I will. Please check original post.

Comment: @user2200321 see my answer replace `form` and email.php edit and test again

Answer (score 0):

One approach: Add a hidden field to your form

```
<!-- ignore that backslash -->
echo "<input type='hidden' name='output' value='$escaped_output' />";
```

(where `$escaped_output = htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES);`), then retrieve that value:

```
$message = $_POST['output'];
// $message now contains last page's $output
```